# Getting a Type error when loading data from API in react using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typegraphql

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR in src/Components/Pages/Languages/LanguagesPage.tsx:41:29
> TS2339: Property 'languageId' does not exist on type '[]'.
> 39 |
>
>   40 |         {data.languages.map((language: []) => (
>   41 |           
>   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^
>   42 |             {language.languageId} - {language.name}
>   43 |
>   44 |         ))}
>
> ERROR in src/Components/Pages/Languages/LanguagesPage.tsx:42:23
> T.  S2339: Property 'languageId' does not exist on type '[]'.
> 40 |         {data.languages.map((language: []) => (
> 41 |           
> 42 |             {language.languageId} - {language.name}
> |                       ^^^^^^^^^^
> 43 |           
> 44 |         ))}
> 45 |
>
> ERROR in src/Components/Pages/Languages/LanguagesPage.tsx:42:47
> TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '[]'.
> 40 |         {data.languages.map((language: []) => (
> 41 |           
> 42 |             {language.languageId} - {language.name}
> |                                               ^^^^
> 43 |           
> 44 |         ))}
> 45 |

I can see my data in the log.  I just can not finger out how to get it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CRMl.png)

Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';  import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

 const GET_LANGUAGES_QUERY = gql` query Query { languages { languageId name
    }   }  `;

 export const LanguagesPage: React.FC = () => { const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_LANGUAGES_QUERY);

if (error) return <p>Error Getting Data</p>; if (loading) return <p>Loading</p>; console.log(data);

return (
    <main>
      <div>current Language: Tabla</div>
      <h3>Which Language do you want to Learn?</h3>
        {data.languages.map((language: []) => (
          <li key={language.languageId}>
            {language.languageId} - {language.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      </main>
     );
```

Comment: Just remove the [] type from the language variable inside the map callback.

Comment: I suppose this is typescript error due to the line where you wrote `language: []`. I suppose `language` is an object, not an array. Remove [] or update it whith the correct type

Answer (score 0):

```
 data.languages.map((language: [])
```

Here you are saying that every item of languages is an array but it's an object instead

Answer (score 0):

Is **language** actually an array? Try console logging the *typeof* and contents of the languages variable.

If it is an array, you cannot use the dot syntax to access contents. You will need to rethink the way you extract `languageId` and `name`.

If it is an object, stop using the `[]` in `language: []`, change it to `{}` and the rest of it should work just fine.